# Ext.TabPanel html help

Tags: extjs

```
add({
     title: args.node.id,
     iconCls: 'tabs',
     items: [{html: '<code class="prettyprint"><?php\necho \'Hello World!\';</code>', width: '100%', hieght: '100%', plain: true}],
     closable: true
}).show();
```

I am running the above method on Ext.TabPanel and it is returning '' as the html...

If I do

```
<code class="prettyprint"><html><head><title>Whatever</title></head><body.The body!</body></html></code>
```

It just renders `The body!`... how can I get it to display the source code??

Many thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform all the `<` and `>` into `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to include the markup in the HTML of your page, wrapped in a div with an id, then pull that into your Panel via the `contentEl` config using that id.  Any sort of nontrivial HTML content will very quickly devolve into a world of pain if you try to use the html config for this.  HTML-encoding, line breaks, indenting, etc. -- just format the HTML as it's intended to be done -- in HTML.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. However the content is being loaded via AJAX as a string.

Comment: In that case I would recommend using the autoLoad config as shown in the second example on this page: http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/tabs/tabs.html

As you can see if you look at the code, the contents loaded via autoLoad (internally via UpdateManager) are automatically HTML-encoded.